# module 'tensorlayer.layers' has no attribut 'DeConv3dLayer'

Tags: tensorlayer

Using tensorlayer 1.2 (for compatibility reasons), I get this error, although in the documentation of tensorlayer v1.2 DeConv3dLayer is in the layer list.

Comment: Could you show us the piece of code that runs into this error?

Comment: network = tl.layers.DeConv3dLayer(network, act=tf.nn.relu, shape=(3, 1, 1, 32, 1), output_shape=(batch_size, 6, 192, 256, 32),
                                      strides=(1, 2, 1, 1, 1), padding='SAME', name='deconv_layer1')

Comment: how is your tensorlayer import command?

Comment: import tensorlayer as tl